# Filled model with extra response using Rx

Tags: java, android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-android

I'm new with Rx java and my current task is I have 2 requests

```
@GET(NEWS_LIST)
fun getNews(): Observable<NewsResponse>

@GET
fun getNewsImage(@Url url: String): Observable<NewsImage>
```

and I'd want to add image url to 1st response model from 2nd one. 2nd one depends on 1st one. How is it possible to merge them in Rx stream?

So 1st request returns me list of news, then I need to call `getNewsImage(url)` for each item with url from this model, parse real image url from second response, add it to `news` object and get final list with filled models
Thanks for any advice

Comment: `flatMap` will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getNews()
        .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it.getTopicsList()) } //or Observable.from() if you use RxJava1
        .flatMap({ getNewsImage(it) }, { topic, imageUrl ->
            topic.imageUrl = imageUrl
            return@flatMap topic
        })
        .toList()
```

Second `flatMap` combines items from the source Observable with the Observable triggered by those source items, and emits these combinations. [More info](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#flatMap(rx.functions.Func1,%20rx.functions.Func2))

Comment: Thanks, 2nd flatMap drives me nuts, I hope I'll get used to functional programing

Answer (score 2):

if i got correctly: 1st response is `List<>` or some `Collection`. So you can do like:

```
getNews().from()
    .flatmap(new Func1<1stResponseItem, 2dnResponseItem>() {
        @Override
        public 2dnResponseItem call(1stResponseItem response) {
            return getNewsImage(response.getImageUrl());
        }
    })
    .tolist()
```

**P.S.** Docs about [`.from()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html) , about [`toList()`](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.com/2015/11/rxjava-operators-tolist.html)